# how to read httppostedfile multiple times without saving in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I'm trying to insert multiple records with excel file to database. Scenerio is, the user selects the excel file from his hard drive then the code reads first row and shows it as the title columns. These columns are not ordered. So user matches right columns with drop down.

Everything is okay until now. But after matching I have to read the file again from another action. But i am not saving file to server. Is there any way to read or hold the file in variable or session?

My code similiar like this

```
public JsonResult ExcelUpload(FormCollection formCollection)
{
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ExcelFile"];
        }
}
```

Comment: I imagine just saving the file to a temporary is going to be a lot more stable and effective than storing the file data in session state.  Why not just write the file to the file system somewhere?

Comment: You should store it temporarily somewhere you wish because you need to handle file operations like reading the content etc. Therefore; doing all these using in-memory streams will probably require much more effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "another action", you mean a different HTTP request, then you can't do that without it persisting somewhere.

Comment: How is this going to keep the file across requests?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I read it as reusing the file in the same request. Updating my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Better read file in data table by using library [given here](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

//1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
//...
//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
//...
//3. DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
//...
//4. DataSet - Create column names from first row
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

//5. Data Reader methods
while (excelReader.Read())
{
    //excelReader.GetInt32(0);
}

//6. Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
excelReader.Close();
```

and store DataSet into session for further processing.